# How do i limit the text field for hour and second?

Tags: ios, swift

Suppose i have a text field that takes minute and hour as input. Now how can i limit the text field for hour upto only 24 and minutes field to 60.

Comment: add a check in your `UITextFieldDelegate` method `didEndEditing` method, and check those values

Comment: Some hints more ....i know this but cannot create idea how to check

Comment: you are using only one `UITextField` or two of them?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should consider using a UIPickerView instead. That's a more appropriate control for selecting limited values, and easier for the user also.

Answer (score 1):

A text field's contents can be controlled via its delegate methods, including one that asks if it [shouldChangeCharacters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield).  If user types something out of bounds, it can be corrected then, or even disallowed by returning `false`.

But a good UI practice is to not let user make an error to begin with.  That's the reason for [pickers](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-controls/pickers/).

Answer (score 0):

Make your ViewController class conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, set `minuteField.delegate = self` and `hourField.delegate = self`, then implement the `shouldChangeCharactersIn range` function and check that the input is numeric and that the number of characters <= 2. You can use `didEndEditing` to check that the number is in your expected range.

```
extension VC: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == minuteField {
            guard let minuteText = textField.text, let minutes = Int(minuteText) else {return}
            if minutes < 0 || minutes > 60 {
                textField.text = ""
            }
        } else if textField == hourField {
            guard let hourText = textField.text, let hours = Int(hourText) else { return }
            if hours < 0 || hours > 24 {
                textField.text = ""
            }
        }
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if string.isEmpty {
            return true
        } else if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) != nil {
            return false
        } else if let numberOfChars = textField.text?.characters.count, numberOfChars >= 2 {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite right, I think.  You must first compute what the text *will be* after the replacement (stringByReplacingOccurancesInRange), then test that string for validity.

Comment: @danh you're right, I was wrong. Tested my code and corrected it, now it is working correctly.

Comment: It's better - you're testing whether the added string contains digits.  The OP is aiming to restrict the numeric value of the whole input.  A more thorough approach is to form a string based on the current text, and range being changed...  `textField.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString`.  (remember, the user might be pasting in text anywhere in the field).  Test that candidate input for validity (e.g. if its intValue < 60, or whatever).

Comment: At the moment I am testing if the value is correct or not in `textFieldDidEndEditing` and replacing the text with an empty string if it's incorrect, but I'll give your idea a try, thanks for the input.